# Dispose pattern for fields created not in ctor?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

Suppose the following class:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    protected MyDisposableType1 _object1;
    protected MyDisposableType2 _object2;

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public StartActivity1()
    {
        _object1 = new MyDisposableType1();
    }

    public StopActivity1()
    {
        _object1.Dispose();
        _object1 = null;
    }

    public StartActivity2()
    {
        _object2 = new MyDisposableType2();
    }

    public StopActivity2()
    {
        _object2.Dispose();
        _object2 = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

According to [Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx) I should implement the `IDisposeable` because my class owns fields of disposable types. But all of the Dispose pattern examples I find deals with disposable fields created in ctor. And in this case the dispose pattern seems clear. But what if the user can create and destroy my disposable field multiple times during `MyClass` lifecycle? Should I use the Dispose pattern as well or maybe there are some use cases?

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote, seems like a reasonable question to me. I wonder if this design problem has emerged because of incorrect packaging of your logic in a single class. Do methods StartActivity1() & StartActivity2() share class instance state?

Comment: @camelCase Sorry I didn't get you question, what you mean "Do methods StartActivity1() & StartActivity2() share class instance state?"

Comment: I meant could the logic for activity-1 and activity-2 be decoupled into separate classes with shared logic (but not instance state) in a base class? I ask because I wondered how your pattern design dilemma arose in the first place. Anyhow you have good answers to your main question.

Comment: I got it, it doesn't matter I guess. This is abstract example.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you try disposing your fields in the Dispose-method too.

There will be something like

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _object1?.Dispose();
        _object2?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The "?"-Operator will be used, if the object is null. With this you get no exceptions if the stop method (i.e. "StopActivity2") is already called.

Comment: Sure I can do this. But user expects that he is not able to use MyClass after call the `Dispose()`. But he actually can because he can call StartActivity() again.

Comment: Normally Disposable classes will be used with the using, keyword. And with that, everything works fine.

Comment: I can't use `MyClass` with `using` because I call `StartActivity()` and `StopActivity()` from very other parts of code actually. So, this is my question - maybe Dispose pattern should be some modified for my specific task?

Comment: Of course there are some cases where you can't use the using keyword. But, I normally use the Disposable pattern for the calling class to. may you can use the using keyword one more scope away

Answer (score 1):

You should not let user to call methods that rely on disposed objects after `MyClass` is disposed. you can simply prevent this by using a Boolean value.

```
bool _disposed;

public StartActivity1()
{
    if(_disposed) return; // or throw exception.
    _object1 = new MyDisposableType1();
}

public StopActivity1()
{
    _object1?.Dispose();
    _object1 = null;
}

//...

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
         _object1?.Dispose();
         _object2?.Dispose();            
         _disposed = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call about preventing reuse post disposal. Is this official advice written in pattern docs or your own personal refinement for the situation presented in the question?

Comment: This is official, look at [Dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) article. Check out [ObjectDisposedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: This pattern is used because after `Dispose()` called the state of `MyClass` becomes imposible to use, right? But in my case it is not so because disposable object is created not in ctor and so it can be created again and the user can continue use `MyClass` by calling `StartActivity()` ..

Comment: You are right. If this answers your questions please consider accepting it. thanks ;) @gustav